# Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysqli

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\tourist\AddFavorites.php:20
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

thrown in
**C:\xampp\htdocs\tourist\AddFavorites.php** on line

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$place_id = $_POST['place_id'];

$sth = ("select count(*) as count from favorites WHERE place_id=$place_id
    AND user_id=$user_id");
        
       $result = $con->query($sth);

if($result['count']>0){
            
             $output = array(
            'status'=>"0",
            'operation'=>"already exists"
            );
            
            echo json_encode($output);
            $db = null;
            
            return;
        }
        else{
..}
```

and line number 20 is if($result['count']>0) I've looked for existing solutions but it's still not working.

Comment: Check manuals and see what is the returned value of `query` (or just `var_dump` it)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After running the query

```
$result = $con->query($sth);
```

`$result` is not an Array, it is usually a Resource or TRUE or FALSE. You can check your result for error like this

```
if (!$result){
// This is an error
}
```

If you want to check for number of rows you can do it like this

```
if (mysql_num_rows ($result) > 0){
// No or rows greater than 0
}
```

I strongly suggest to check out the PHP manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Or even better use mysqli

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Which you should really be using by now...

Comment: Do not mix `mysql` and `mysqli`. It's absolutely different apis.

Comment: @u_mulder I know, they are completely different APIs but somehow I find mysqli (i)improved more suitable for starting with mysql

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) cannot be used this way. It basically represents all rows fetched by query, so you need to fetch a row from it by one of its method (check the manual).

You probably want sth like this

```
$result = $con->query($sth);
$row = $result->fetch_array();
if($row['count']>0){
 // ...
}
```